# ReactiveCocoa preferable way of firing RACSignal

Tags: reactive-cocoa

I want a RACSignal to fire, on some external activity, for ex:  a Silent APNS notification. I can achieve this using rac_signalForSelector as follows:

```
- (id) init {

if ((self = [super init])) {
    [self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(silentAPNS)]
    flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        // Perform some activity
         [self onSilentAPNSNotification];
      }]
      subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    }]; 
}
 return self;
}

- (void) silentAPNS {
 NSLog(@“silent apns called”);
}


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

   [self silentAPNS];
}
```

Although the above works, it can get hard to follow the code, especially since silentAPNS method itself doesn’t do much

I can instead declare a RACSubject property and send a message to it as follows

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) RACSubject * silentAPNSSignal;
- (id) init {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
      self.silentAPNSSignal = [RACSubject subject];
      [self.silentAPNSSignal
         flattenMap:^RACStream *(id value) {
        // Perform some activity
         [self onSilentAPNSNotification];
      }]
      subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    }]; 
}
 return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
  [self.silentAPNSSignal sendCompleted];
}

- (void) silentAPNS {
  NSLog(@“silent pans called”);
  [self.silentAPNSSignal sendNext:nil];
}
```

The document discourages the use of RACSubject, but the second example is easier to understand. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could use the `takeUntil` operator and pass in `self.rac_willDeallocSignal` to mimic the `dealloc` method you've written in the second example. Also, just a note on RAC, I'm pretty sure it's bad form to have an empty `subscribeNext` block, so you probably want to move the `[self onSilentAPNSNotification]` out of the `flattenMap` and into the `subscribeNext` block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `takeUntil` operator and pass in `self.rac_willDeallocSignal` to mimic the `dealloc` method you've written in the second example. In general, I think it's best to avoid `RACSubject` in all but the very edge cases. I'm not too experienced with RAC, but I recommend the YouTube video on "RACifying non RAC code" (it's on Github's channel in their RAC playlist).

Also, just a note on RAC, I'm pretty sure it's bad form to have an empty `subscribeNext` block, so you probably want to move the `[self onSilentAPNSNotification]` out of the `flattenMap` and into the `subscribeNext` block.